# MySQLi Transaction Spaghetti Hell

Tags: php, transactions, mysqli, commit, autocommit

I have a class with more than a hundred functions/methods in it. Many of them require to run MySQLi query within a transaction. So, in a simple form, most of the functions look like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private $connection = ...; // mysqli connection
    public function a () {
        $this->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
        // do something and run multiple queries
        $this->connection->commit();
    }
    public function b () {
        $this->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
        // do something and run multiple queries
        $this->connection->commit();
    }
}
// to run the code:
$myclass = new MyClass();
$myclass->a(); // all queries are run inside a transaction
$myclass->b(); // all queries are run inside a transaction
```

The concept is simple: Every time I run a public function/method, it starts a transaction and commits before ending the function/method.
Now, my problem is... what if I want to run a method within another method, while keeping both methods public and callable by callers outside the class??? For example:

```
class MyClass {
    private $connection = ...; // mysqli connection
    public function a () {
        $this->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
        // do something and run multiple queries
        $this->connection->commit();
    }
    public function b () {
        $this->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
        // do something and run multiple queries
        $this->a(); // running function a inside function b here
        $this->connection->commit();
    }
}
// to run the code:
$myclass = new MyClass();
$myclass->a(); // all queries are run inside a transaction
$myclass->b(); // transaction is not working as I initially wished. This function consists of more than one commit, hence, not everything is run inside one transaction
```

Using extra variables for manual if/else checking, I suppose I can solve the problem above with two functions. However, my problem here is that I have multiple, possibly nearly a hundred, functions/methods that act like the above. I don't think I can use a few if/else to handle such complicated problem of transaction spaghetti hell.

How might I resolve this?

P.S:

The above is just a simplification of my class. To make things even more complicated, in my class I didn't just use:

```
function func() {
    $this->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
    // do something
    $this->connection->commit();
}
```

Instead, I did something like this:

```
function func() {
    if ($result = $this->connection->query('SELECT @@autocommit')) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $originalAutoCommitValue = $row[0];
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    if (!$originalAutoCommitValue) {
        $this->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
    }
    // do something...
    $this->connection->commit();
    $this->connection->autocommit($originalAutoCommitValue);
}
```

This will allow the function/method in my class to start a transaction, commit the transaction and return the auto commit state back to before. This is really clumsy, but I hope that the users of my class have their choice of whether to use transaction/commit outside the class. I hope this approach will not affect their original state of auto commit before using any of my class' methods.

**UPDATE**

I have added the following properties and two functions in the class:

```
private $connectionTransactionStack = 0;
private $connectionOriginalAutoCommitState = NULL;

private function startTransaction() {
    if (is_null($this->connectionOriginalAutoCommitState)) {
        if ($result = $this->connection->query('SELECT @@autocommit')) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $this->connectionOriginalAutoCommitState = $row[0];
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    }
    if ($this->connectionOriginalAutoCommitState === 1) {
        $this->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
    }
    $this->connectionTransactionStack++;
}
private function commitTransaction() {
    $this->connectionTransactionStack--;
    if ($this->connectionTransactionStack < 1) {
        $this->connectionTransactionStack = 0;
        if ($this->connectionOriginalAutoCommitState === 1) {
            $this->connection->commit();
            $this->connection->autocommit($this->connectionOriginalAutoCommitState);
        }
    }
}
```

So, now when I want to run original functions, I can just do this:

```
class MyClass {

    public function a () {
        $this->startTransaction();
        // do something and run multiple queries
        $this->commitTransaction();
    }
    public function b () {
        $this->startTransaction();
        // do something and run multiple queries
        $this->a(); // running function a inside function b here
        $this->commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

As long as I commit all transactions if I started any in any methods, the non-final $this->commitTransaction() will not run a real mysqli->commit(), but the final $this->commitTransaction() will run mysqli->commit if necessary (depending on the initial state before the first run any methods inside my class). So if I want to run:

```
$this->a();
```

or

```
$this->b();
```

, it doesn't matter at all because there is a stack to count the transaction I would have started. However, in real, there is only one transaction to be started and committed.

Would this be a solution to my problem above?

Comment: Maybe you can show use 3-4 REAL code for functions you have, and we we might be able to figure out a descent to achieve what you want.

Comment: I don't mind to show the real code here, but I would say it's little point of doing so, because in real-world projects, the above requirement is quite common for PHP-MySQL interactions, especially when there need transactions to achieve something. For example, let's say I have a series of SELECT queries, and each query may depends on the result of previous query. Another example would be running a SELECT query and then do an UPDATE, for which, depends on the result of the previous SELECT query.

Comment: Are you always doing the same stuff with startTransaction() and commitTransaction() undendently which function is called?

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to **delete**:

```
$this->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
$this->connection->commit();
```

**in every function** that is relevant (a,b)
and then wrap them around your function calls.

```
class MyClass {
    private $connection = ...; // mysqli connection
    public function a () {
        // do something and run multiple queries
    }
    public function b () {
        // do something and run multiple queries
        $this->a(); // running function a inside function b here
    }
}
// to run the code:
$myclass = new MyClass();

$myclass->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
$myclass->a(); // all queries are run inside a transaction
$myclass->b(); 
$this->connection->commit();
```

**UPDATE:**

OR maybe better , use a wrapper-function for calling the functions inside the class:

```
$myclass->doTransaction('a'); 
$myclass->doTransaction('b'); 

function doTransaction($functionCall) {
    //Do some sanitizing of the functionCall-variable
    $this->connection->autocommit(FALSE);
    call_use_func($functionCall); 
    $this->connection->commit();
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... this may be logically correct, but not quite what I want. 


You see, I did all those committing within the functions is mainly because I want the users of the class to use the functions without worrying anything about transactions... but of course, they can optionally choose to deal with transaction if they want, as shown in the "P.S" section of my question.

Comment: @user2526586 - ok, but you could do a wrapper-function that calls the actual function you want. Wait a moment, I should update answer.

Comment: Did you mean calling: $myclass->doTransaction('a', $param1, $param2, $param3, $param4...); and inside doTransaction: call_user_func($functionCall, $functionParam1, $functionParam2, $functionParam3, $functionParam4...); If so... hmmm... well, I guess this works, except it is a little messy and not very user-friendly for other users of the class...

Comment: @user2526586 - A developer _has_ to do this work, because only he can know what belongs into a single transaction. Your functions are similar to a grouped autocommit, and will allways interrupt the usage of a higher-level transaction.

Comment: @user2526586 - yes I meant that (I didn't include any $params because there weren't any params in the functions a and b). It might be messy, but I'm really not a wizard :-) If you want it properly done, then you'll will have to rewrite the code entirely after your specifications. There are not shortcuts for getting good quality code from a large ugly code-base.